# What might cause a 503 Service Unavailable for reports area of an asp.net mvc3 application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, iis-7.5

We're switching our MVC3 application from IIS 6 to 7.5.  I'm working on setting up my local development environment on Windows 7.  The app works fine for the most part, but I just discovered that ONE out of the many different MVC Areas I have doesn't work.

When I try hit an action under this area, I get a 503 Service Unavailable error back.  This does not happen anywhere else in my application.

- There is only one application pool for the whole website.
- MVC 3
- .Net 4.0
- 64 bit
- Failed request tracing doesn't see these requests.
- There is nothing relevant in the Windows application or system logs.
- The area works fine under visual studio 2010 cassini, problem happens when I run it under local iis 7.5 (not express)
- App pool isn't crashing or otherwise stopped
- There's nothing in my ELMAH log
- Everyone full control on entire tree in the filesystem security
- The url is http://localhost/reports

I'm totally stumped.  I can't find any evidence that IIS is even getting the request at all.  Is there some other log file beside the ones I listed?

[Update]
Is there any way to view the http.sys URL reservations? I have found some talk about SQL Reporting services calling dibs on /Reports url.

Comment: Do you have any other IIS modules or applications that handle that URL?

Comment: Not unless there's something on default IIS 7 install that would handle that url.

Comment: If you change it to /reports2 do you still get the same problem...?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I figured it out.  It was due to SQL Reporting services having reserved the http://+:80/Reports url in http.sys.

I didn't actually have reporting services installed, but it apparently still reserved the url.

I fixed it with the following command:

```
netsh http delete urlacl url=http://+:80/Reports
```

Comment: Thanks! This issue was weird as hell, but SO to the rescue again.

Comment: Sorted, not sure I'd have ever worked that out myself!

Comment: Thank you. This helped me to solve my issue which was haunting me for some days

Answer (score 4):

Check the account / IIS -> Application Pool -> Advanced Settings -> Process Model -> Identity under which your pool is running. I had my password changed, and didn't get a log on invalid password, but rather assemlby load failure, which in turn caused the app pool to be shut off, and the "503 Service Unavailable" was given to the user.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is, I had the same problem with my http://ApplicationURL/**Reports**

And yes the SSRS was the issue.

A better solution for this one is

1. OpenReporting Services Configuration Manager.
2. Connect to your local service usually COMPUTERNAME\MSSQLSERVER
3. Go to "Report Manager URL" Option
4. Modify your virtual directory with another name instead of Reports.

Just remember with this change you reports for SSRS will be in the name that you defined.

Carlos

Comment: I knew it wasn't my mvc code. Haha!  it was just too strange of a error, even though it's common. 
Thank you, this was most absolutely the correct answer for me. Not sure why it hasn't been upvoted. Surely others encounter this. You know... with Microsoft claiming the /Reports/ path on all port 80 hosts.... ridiculous. Only ms can get away with such things.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any ODBC or other components in this area that you are not anywhere else?  I have experienced this error (or one similar, can't remember off the top of my head) when running the app pool in 64bit mode and the underlying calls are referencing at 32bit 'something'.  You could try enabling 32bit applications in the application pool settings to see if it affects the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before it is related to SQL Reporting services
You can follow this approach to fix this problem:

Log on to the server that hosts SSRS.

**Go to Start > Programs > SQL Server 2008 R2 > Configuration Tools > Reporting Services Configuration Manager**

Connect to the server in question (usually your local server)

Go to the Web Service URL section

Change the TCP port to an open port other than port 80 (81 happened to work on my server) and hit Apply

Go to the Report Manager URL section

Click Advanced

Click the entry with a TCP port of 80 and then click the Edit button.

Change the TCP Port entry to the same thing you changed it to in the Web Service URL section previously and Click OK.

Click OK again.